# Ubuntu App CMake Build error 255

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I have an app in the Ubuntu store called Body Status. You can find the source code on [Github](https://github.com/avi-software/bmicalc).

When I open the source code in the Ubuntu SDK to update something and then build it again, I get this error instead.

```
make[2]: *** [po/CMakeFiles/bmiCalc.desktop] Error 255
```

I have also noticed that the project opened incorrectly using the build target name `all` instead to `default`.

If I create a new project it builds correctly without any errors.

**UPDATE**: I solve it, it was problem with one of my .po files, that has to be fix..